# How can I create a random email reminder in Gmail or Inbox by Gmail?

Tags: gmail, inbox-by-gmail

I would like to create a random email reminder in Gmail or Inbox by Gmail to for instance:

- create a reminder for myself to tag a Flickr image
- read one of my Pocket articles
- to perform other regular tasks that I want to do sometimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inbox by Gmail allows you to create a "reminder" (pin) and snooze it to "someday".